# How to remove diacritics from text?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, diacritics

I am making a swedish website, and swedish letters are å, ä, and ö.

I need to make a string entered by a user to become url-safe with PHP.

Basically, need to convert all characters to underscore, all EXCEPT these:

```
 A-Z, a-z, 1-9
```

and all swedish should be converted like this:

'å' to 'a' and 'ä' to 'a' and 'ö' to 'o' (just remove the dots above).

The rest should become underscores as I said.

Im not good at regular expressions so I would appreciate the help guys!

Thanks

NOTE: NOT URLENCODE...I need to store it in a database... etc etc, urlencode wont work for me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
// normalize data (remove accent marks) using PHP's *intl* extension
$data = normalizer_normalize($data);

// replace everything NOT in the sets you specified with an underscore
$data = preg_replace("#[^A-Za-z1-9]#","_", $data);
```

Comment: Please mention that `normalizer_normalize()` is part of the _intl_ PHP extension that is not always active. This extension was added to the core in PHP 5.3, but in most linux distributions it isn't active by default. For instance, in Debian it is in the separate package _php5-intl_. If you can't install/activate it, try _ext/iconv_. instead

Comment: @Mytskine I've added the comment. Thanks for pointing that out: it was on my default for me so I didn't give it a second thought.

Answer (score 26):

This should be useful which handles almost all the cases.

```
function Unaccent($string)
{
    return preg_replace('~&([a-z]{1,2})(?:acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml|caron);~i', '$1', htmlentities($string, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'));
}
```

Comment: This looks amazing, but has problems with for example greek characters

Comment: This is the most elegant and creative solution i have found for this problem... Congrats!

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work with ř, ž, ť, ň, ů, ě, č, ď (Czech)

Answer (score 23):

Use [iconv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) to convert strings from a given encoding to ASCII, then replace non-alphanumeric characters using [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$input = 'räksmörgås och köttbullar'; // UTF8 encoded
$input = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $input);
$input = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '_', $input);
echo $input;
```

Result:

```
raksmorgas_och_kottbullar
```

Comment: You should use "UTF-8" like this : `$data = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $data);` - otherwise you might encounter this notice: "Wrong charset, conversion from `UTF8' to `ASCII//TRANSLIT' is not allowed"

Comment: Please update your answer to include @Hirnhamster's suggestion. Your missing hyphen in 'UTF-8' is affecting other people.

Answer (score 8):

> and all swedish should be converted like this:
>
> 'å' to 'a' and 'ä' to 'a' and 'ö' to 'o' (just remove the dots above).

Use [`normalizer_normalize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php) to get rid of [diacritical marks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic).

> The rest should become underscores as I said.

Use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with a pattern of `[\W]` (i.o.w: any character which doesn't match letters, digits or underscore) to replace them by underscores.

Final result should look like:

```
$data = preg_replace('[\W]', '_', normalizer_normalize($data));
```

Answer (score 5):

If intl php extension is enabled, you can use Transliterator like this :

```
protected function removeDiacritics($string)
{
    $transliterator = \Transliterator::create('NFD; [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; NFC;');
    return $transliterator->transliterate($string);
}
```

To remove other special chars (not diacritics only like 'æ')

```
protected function removeDiacritics($string)
{
    $transliterator = \Transliterator::createFromRules(
        ':: Any-Latin; :: Latin-ASCII; :: NFD; :: [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; :: NFC;',
        \Transliterator::FORWARD
    );
    return $transliterator->transliterate($string);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're just interested in making things URL safe, then you want [`urlencode`](https://www.php.net/urlencode).

> Returns a string in which all
> non-alphanumeric characters except -_.
> have been replaced with a percent (%)
> sign followed by two hex digits and
> spaces encoded as plus (+) signs. It
> is encoded the same way that the
> posted data from a WWW form is
> encoded, that is the same way as in
> application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> media type. This differs from the »
> RFC 1738 encoding (see rawurlencode())
> in that for historical reasons, spaces
> are encoded as plus (+) signs.

If you really want to strip all non A-Z, a-z, 1-9 (what's wrong with `0`, by the way?), then you want:

```
$mynewstring = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z1-9]/', '', $str);
```

Comment: If you want to make it safe, then you do want urlencode. The fact you want to store it in a database is beside the point (other than that you will want to escape it for your SQL insertation query in addition to making it url safe).

Comment: You just don't understand. He wants it to be safe to use as a URL, but not THAT safe. He would prefer it fails on a space or ampersand.

Answer (score 2):

as simple as

```
 $str = str_replace(array('å', 'ä', 'ö'), array('a', 'a', 'o'), $str); 
 $str = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/', '_', strtolower($str));
```

assuming you use the same encoding for your data and your code.

Comment: '/[^a-z0-9]+/i' or '/[^A-Za-z0-9]+/' to ignore case

Comment: strtr is more convenient to "translate" sets of characters, like:
 $str = strtr($str,"aëïöü","aeiou"); it doesn't use arrays

Comment: Arrays are cumbercome to maintain a little thousand characters with diacritical marks known at the human world. Just use `normalizer`.

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution is to use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function with search and replace letter arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need fancy regexps to filter the swedish chars, just use the [strtr function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) to "translate" them, like:

```
$your_URL = "www.mäåö.com";
$good_URL = strtr($your_URL, "äåöë etc...", "aaoe etc...");
echo $good_URL;
```

->output: www.maao.com :)

Comment: It is only a maintenance nightmare to cover thousands of those characters known at the human world.