# My php can't find 'normalizer_normalize()' function, why?

Tags: php

How come I can't use normalizer function?

I am using it exactly as I should, ie: $var = normalizer_normalize($str);

I get php error: no such function!

Here is the code:

```
 $headline= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['headline']);
 $ad_id_string=normalizer_normalize($headline);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php), `normalizer_normalize` was included in PHP as of version 5.3.0.  Prior to that, it was available as a PECL extension.  To build it as part of PHP, you'll need to install [internationalization](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intl.setup.php) support.

If you need to provide your own equivalent to the Normalizer class, [`strtr()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) would be a good option.  The only downside is that you will need to provide your own character strings to translate to / from.

Comment: What would you use prior to that then?

All I need to do is convert swedish letters å (a with a ring on it) to a regular a...

Comment: There are answers to help with that on your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770250/how-to-remove-diacritics-from-text