# How to convert special characters entered in form into similar English characters before placing in database?

Tags: php, mysql

e.g. we have form that ask for first name last name country, country is drop down list, but name is free entry. We need to make sure we have no special characters in input field. And instead convert them to english.
e.g.

```
Á -> A,á -> a,Č -> C,č -> c,ď -> d,é -> e,ě -> e,É -> E,Ě -> E,í -> i,Í
-> i,Ň -> N,ň -> n,Ó -> O,ó -> o,Ř -> R,ř -> r,Š -> S,š -> s,ť -> t,Ú -> U,ú -> u,Ů -> U,ů -> u,
Ý -> Y,ý -> y,Ž -> Z,ž -> z
```

Is there some way to do it in php or mysql?

Comment: "We need to make sure we have no special characters in input field": Why? I though MySQL has support for unicode... What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use php function [utf8_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php)

Or detect encoding and change it if it is not utf-8, like below:

```
<?php
//$s is a string from whatever source
mb_detect_encoding($s, "UTF-8") == "UTF-8" ? : $s = utf8_encode($s);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use PHP >= 5.3 then [`normalizer.normalize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/normalizer.normalize.php) should do the job. By the way, the name for what you want to do is *removing diacritics*. If you are using an earlier version of PHP then you should be able to use the same function if you enable the [intl PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) extension (as commented here [How to remove diacritics from text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770250/how-to-remove-diacritics-from-text/1770306#1770306))

**Edit:** Found a related question [How do I remove accents from characters in a PHP string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017599/how-do-i-remove-accents-from-characters-in-a-php-string)