# Codeigniter's url_title() change UTF8 Characters to specified Latin

Tags: php, codeigniter, utf-8, routes

Is it possible to make `url_title()` produce rephrasing of this strings:

```
čolić
nešto
```

Into:

```
colic
nesto
```

I believe that this could be useful with Latin-base UTF8 languages and setting up more pretty and descriptive URLs for non-Latin languages.

Comment: Just to be clear, this has little to do with UTF-8. You just want to convert latin characters with diacritics into similar latin characters without diacritics.

Comment: For example like this: [How to remove diacritics from text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770250/how-to-remove-diacritics-from-text)

Comment: It should be that. Is it possible to alter `url_title()` to do that automatically, without writing additional function?

Comment: I am new to CodeIgniter world, so I forgot that I could extend helpers. Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just tie into the convert_accented_characters function:

```
url_title(convert_accented_characters('čolić'));
```

Comment: what is this function `convert_accented_characters` all about?

Comment: Best bet is to look it up here: 
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/text_helper.html - Also it uses the foreign_chars config so if a translation is missing you can modify that file.

Comment: I've been using CI for almost two years and didn't even know about that function. Nice!

Comment: Don't forget to load both helpers. `$this->load->helper (array ('text', 'url'));`

Answer (score 1):

I'm using

```
$this->load->helper('text');
$string = 'tèst Tést ççÇçandãÃ';
$title = url_title(convert_accented_characters(utf8_encode(strtolower($string)));
// return: test-test-cccandaa
```